# Docker hello world gives 'no space left on device'

Tags: debian, docker, cgroup

The command `docker run hello-world` gives me this error:
`System error: write /dev/cgroup/docker/<hash>/cgroup.procs: no space left on device`

It's a Debian Wheezy, with a 3.16 kernel from backports. (previously upgraded from squeeze)

/dev is mounted as devtmpfs of 10MB `udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=1019797,mode=755)`

Does docker have a config option I need to change?

Full output:

```
$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world 
535020c3e8ad: Pull complete 
af340544ed62: Already exists 
library/hello-world:latest: The image you are pulling has been verified.
Important: image verification is a tech preview feature and should not be relied on to provide security.
Digest: sha256:d5fbd996e6562438f7ea5389d7da867fe58e04d581810e230df4cc073271ea52
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
WARNING: Your kernel does not support memory swappiness capabilities, memory swappiness discarded.
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 0ecfcae485a362fffcbf40e26db61356be62a8093f8bcea5dc37147f1a5a47e0: [8]     System error: write /dev/cgroup/docker/0ecfcae485a362fffcbf40e26db61356be62a8093f8bcea5dc37147f1a5a47e0/cgroup.procs: no space left on
```

Docker info:

```
docker info
Containers: 7
Images: 5
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 19
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 7.796 GiB
Name: ...
ID: WZ7K:E5CI:YYXJ:GXL6:Q2NL:5S27:NL4T:6KMM:Z4PF:4N56:PZI3:NPMY
WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

df:

```
Filesystem              Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                  rootfs    107G   41G   64G  39% /
udev                    devtmpfs   10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                   tmpfs     799M  244K  799M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-label/\x2f ext3      107G   41G   64G  39% /
tmpfs                   tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                   tmpfs     2.4G     0  2.4G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1               ext3       88M   51M   33M  61% /boot
cgroup                  tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/disk/by-label/\x2f ext3      107G   41G   64G  39% /var/lib/docker/aufs
```

Comment: So what is the output of `df`?

Comment: added df output to main question.

Answer (score 1):

Add **cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1** to your grub and reboot the OS.

$ sudo vim /etc/default/grub

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"

$ sudo update-grub

$ sudo reboot

[Reference](http://tombee.co.uk/2014/11/16/kernel-does-not-support-memory-limitation/)

Answer (score 0):

What does "\df /dev/cgroup/" say ? Could it be that the filesystem is "vserver" ? In which case you could have an incompatibility between vserver and docker (which use the same underlying technologies).

On my system, just \df wont show it, but only by explicitely providing the path to df will it show.

It will show in "cat /proc/mounts" as well.